# Mac Dirname of String From Variable

Tags: bash, macos

In my bash_profile I created a deploy function. There I read a path from a file:

```
deployPath=$(jq '.["prod-deploy-path"]' ./package.json)
```

When I print the path, I get the following:

```
"/var/www/user/websitefolder/dist"
```

Now I want to remove the last part of the URL:

```
pwdPath=$(dirname $deployPath)
```

but I receive

```
"/var/www/user/websitefolder/dist
```

(notice the last quotation mark is missing)

If I do the same thing with a fixed string instead of the variable

```
dirname "/var/www/user/websitefolder/dist"
```

I receive what I want to receive:

```
dirname "/var/www/user/websitefolder/"
```

What do I need to write in my bash_profile to get the same result with the variable as with a string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to use the `-r` option for `jq`:

```
deployPath=$(jq -r '.["prod-deploy-path"]' ./package.json)
```

which will output a raw string.

Your problem is not that you got a variable but that the content in the  variable are wrapped in quotes, eg:

```
with_quotes='"something here"'
without_quotes='something here'

echo "$with_quotes"    # "something here"
echo "$without_quotes" # something here
```

`jq` will by default print a JSON encoded string. This also means that if your string contains double quotes they will be escaped like this: `"hello \"world"`

From `man jq`:

```
--raw-output / -r
  With this option, if the filter's result is a string then it will be written
  directly to standard  output rather  than  being formatted as a JSON string
  with quotes. This can be useful for making jq filters talk to non-JSON-based
  systems
```